# Eliminar registro de tabla con llave compuesta

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

Estoy empezando a usar EntityFramework y MVC en C# .NET, y tengo un problema al tratar de eliminar un registro de una tabla que usa llave compuesta.

**Controlador:**

```
// GET: DocenteCursoes/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(string curso, string docente)
    {
        if (curso == null && docente == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        DocenteCurso docenteCurso = db.DocenteCurso.Find(curso, docente);
        if (docenteCurso == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(docenteCurso);
    }

    // POST: DocenteCursoes/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string curso, string docente)
    {
        DocenteCurso docenteCurso = db.DocenteCurso.Find(curso, docente);
        db.DocenteCurso.Remove(docenteCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

**Modelo:**

```
[Table("DocenteCurso")]
public partial class DocenteCurso
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Curso { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Docente { get; set; }
}
```

**Vista:**

```
<div>
<h4>DocenteCurso</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
</dl>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

No tengo problemas con una **llave primaria** pero con una **llave compuesta** no sé cómo hacerlo, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No existe dos llaves primarias en una tabla, seguramente a lo que te refieres es a una llave compuesta.

Comment: asi es, es una llave compuesta

Comment: la vista esa es incorrecta, donde envias el curso y docente al action delete?

Comment: @MauroPetrini si, lo que ocurre es que la vista fue generada automaticamente pero no se que debo agregarle o como hacer para que funcione al momento de borrar, logre modificar la vista al guardar y ya funciona pero no se como eliminar la del eliminar

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que quieras eliminar de una tabla y que esta relacionada, porque pasar los dos campos si es de la Tabla Docente, únicamente pasas el id de ese docente y después usas una transacción para eliminar los cursos, o lo contrario enviar el id del curso y eliminar a los docentes; así te aseguras de tener información congruente en la base de datos. yo uso el siguiente código, en el cual retorno un "succes" si realmente se eliminaron.

En el metodo ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var prov = db.MtoProveedores.Find(id);

        if (prov == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        var response = DBProvee.Delete(prov, User.Identity.Name);

        if (response.succeeded)
        {
            return Json(new { success = response.succeeded, }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
            //return Json(new { success = response.succeeded });
        }

        return View(prov);
    }
```

y una clase

```
 public static Response Delete(MtoProveedor view, string UserName)
    {
         var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
        var date = DateTime.Now;

        using (var Transaccion = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                /*===============================================================
                  ELIMINAR INVERSIONISTAS
                ===============================================================*/

                var inv = db.MtoInversionistas.Where(d => d.MtoProveedorId == view.MtoProveedorId);
                foreach (var Details in inv)
                {
                    db.MtoInversionistas.Remove(Details);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                /*===============================================================
                  ELIMINAR REPRESENTACIONES LEGALES
                ===============================================================*/
                var replegal = db.MtoRepLegales.Where(d => d.MtoProveedorId == view.MtoProveedorId);
                foreach (var Details in replegal)
                {
                    db.MtoRepLegales.Remove(Details);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                /*===============================================================
                  ELIMINAR PROVEEDOR DEFINITIVAMENTE
                ===============================================================*/
                var proveedor = db.MtoProveedores.Find(view.MtoProveedorId);

                db.MtoProveedores.Remove(proveedor);

                db.SaveChanges();

                Transaccion.Commit();

                return new Response { succeeded = true };                    
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);

                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                return new Response { succeeded = false, Message = raise.Message };
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

en principio no tienes que hacer nada especial. Lo único que falta en tu vista son los inputs que lleven los valores de la clave primaria. Simplemente añadiendo :
`@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Curso)` y `@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Docente)`
en el Post ya recibirás los 2 valores y con eso basta para localizar la instancia a eliminar tal cuál tienes el método.